# ECC private key generation collision

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptocurrency

I am generating ECC private keys. however I noticed that since ECC private key is just a BigInteger. e.g. `spec256k1` says private key is anywhere between [0~2^256-1].

my question is, if everyone is using `Random(32)` to generate a 32bytes private key, there is not likely but still possible situation that 2 people could generate the same private key. therefore also same public key.

so if this happens on blockchain like Bitcoin or Etheruem, does that mean those 2 people are in theory sharing the same account? or wallet address?

maybe I am missing some details here. Please guide me.

**Edit:**

thanks for everyone's answer here.

the reason why I was asking this is because first I wonder if there is any protection against collision in the system. however, if there is, and you are told you had a collision, that basically means you figured out someone else's private key...

second reason is, I was considering generating a long(64bits) and then cast into BigInteger(32bytes) to be the private key. however, that will have a much higher collision chance due to the fact that I will only have a private key space of `2^64`.

Comment: I believe that is correct, not likely but possible

Comment: If you pick 64 bits uniformly at random and the remaining 192 as zero, you are practically guaranteed never to get someone _else's_ key, but you'll likely get a collision after a billion keys, and someone _else_ can probably guess one of your keys with a large but plausible distributed computing effort.

Comment: @SqueamishOssifrage actually, if you knew the format of the keys (i.e. which bits were zero), then someone could run a Big Step/Little Step attack, and recover your key with a laptop (circa $2^{32}$ space and time)

Comment: Technically ECDSA does not allow privatekey == 0 or >= the order of the generator and group; see https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/30269/are-all-possible-ec-private-keys-valid . Since the privatekey normally should be random, and the chance of a random value violating these constraints is tiny, in practice people sometimes don't bother with them. Nevertheless I would consider someone writing a spec who doesn't even mention them ignorant or negligent, and not trust any crypto code they produce.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume that there are $2^{50}$ keys out there. Then calculating one of these keys by chance is $2^{50} \over 2^{255}$ for each calculation or a chance of one in $2^{205}$. Now say that you generate $2^{64}$ keys then you'd still only have a [chance of one out of $2^{91}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_2(1+-+(1-+(2%5E50)%5E2+%2F+%7B2%5E255%7D)+%5E+(2%5E64))) of hitting the right key.

Note that making sure that you hit a key would however require $2^{50}$ tests, and knowledge of $2^{50}$ operations by the public key of course. To test a single key the situation is significantly worse, the chance of finding it after 
$2^{64}$ tries is only [one out of $2^{191}$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_2(1+-+(1-+1+%2F+%7B2%5E255%7D)+%5E+(2%5E64))).

Chances of hitting the right key increase somewhat if you make sure you make sure that you don't generate the same key again. For instance you could start at a specific value and then simply test each following value. But that won't increase your chances by much and the calculation is too hairy to do here.

This is always what cryptography relies on: that you cannot just *guess* the private key. There is no cryptosystem to protect against that. And there doesn't need to be because the chance of generating a matching private key is *negligible*.

And think about it, I could guess the value of a coin as well. There is no protection against that either.

---

Note that a chance of one in $2^{91}$ is one in 2475880078570760549798248448 or one in 2 octillion 475 septillion 880 sextillion 78 quintillion 570 quadrillion 760 trillion 549 billion 798 million 248 thousand 448 (using the [short scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales)).

Comment: In other words, you are 23000 times more likely to win the full Powerball jackpot 4 times in a row than you are of generating the same key as another person

Comment: @RichieFrame That's probably not true.  The Powerball jackpot is probably more gameable than a uniform random 256-bit RNG!  (bugs in the RNG aside)

Comment: To be more precise, if there are $x$ keys generated, the probability that two of them will happen to be the same is approximately $x^2 / 2^{257}$ (assuming $x \lll 2^{128}$).  If we assume $x = 2^{50}$ bitcoin keys are generated worldwide (that's about 100,000 per person on the planet), that gives us a collision probability of about $2^{-157}$; considerably less than the value you give

Comment: I assumed that there would be $2^{128}$ bitcoin keys, which is computationally infeasible by itself (never mind practical). Searching for a collision is kind of pointless if you cannot use it afterwards.

Comment: Actually, if there are $2^{128}$ bitcoin keys generated, the probability that there is a repeat somewhere in there is pretty decent.  Of course, *finding* that pair might be a tad problematic...

Comment: @poncho OK, using the birthday bound was a bit stupid, I've changed the calculations for finding a key out of the $2^{50}$ keys out there. Could you check the calculations? I've linked to the WolframAlpha pages for them.

Comment: thanks guys. according to all your answers, if I do random generate a long(64bit) and then cast it into a BigInteger(32bytes). that in theory works but then will have a significant higher chance to collide if I want to generate a large amount of keys.

Comment: Yes, if you only use 64 bits out of 256 then you sure will have a higher chance of creating a collision.

Answer (score 0):

It's worse than that. There can be a collision even using different private keys.

Each (standard) Bitcoin transaction to you is sent to a 160-bit **hash** of your public key (a.k.a., your **address**). Anyone who owns a public key that has same **hash** will be able to spend your coins. So that's a 80 bits of security, since only half of the keyspace has to be searched, on average, before a match is found [EDIT: a 50% probability of finding match between two previously searched keys, not necessarily ones on the blockchain. See comments.]

The Bitcoin blockchain has ~30 million (25 bits of) public key hashes available to be spent right now. To find a match for any of them, this drops your search space by 25 bits down to 135 bits, leaving 67.5 bits of security "overall".

If two different public keys produce the same hash, and both sign for the same UTXO at the same time, it would be up to the miner to choose which one makes it in.

Another bit or so of security is lost because the public keys are hashed *twice* to make the address, so it's possible for the first hash to be different yet produce a matching second hash.

Comment: 2^80 only gives you a _collision_ which allows you to steal from yourself, not very useful. Hitting _someone else's_ key requires a _preimage_ at 2^159 single-target, reduced to about 2^134 for multi-target as you correctly say. Unless quantum :-)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085
Thanks. Very good to know! :))